# How can I store the values of multiple checkbox when click into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm trying to create a choices of multiple checkbox, and I'm trying to store it into array, and then convert it to string before throwing it into my `setAnswer` state.

```
[

    {
        "choices": "Below 2 yrs. old",
    },
    {
        "choices": "2-5 yrs. old",
    },
    {
        "choices": "6-12 yrs. old",
    },
    {
        "choices": "13-18 yrs. old",
    },
    {
        "choices": "19 yrs. old and above",
    },
    {
        "choices": "Not Applicable",
    }
]
```

So the value here should be in just a single Array, yet it's not joining

[image]

This is my handleChange.js

```
const handleChange = (e) => {

        const value = e.target.value;
        const inputType = e.target.type;
      
        let newChoice = answer.choice;
        let selectedChoices = []

        if (inputType === "radio") {
          newChoice = value;
        } else if (inputType === "checkbox") {
          const isChecked = e.target.checked;
          if (isChecked) {
            selectedChoices.push(value)
          } else {

          }
        }
      
      };
```

This is my checkbox, I'm mapping it.

```
 <input className="toggle-button__state" type="checkbox" name="choice" value={choice.choices} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Comment: try declare `selectedChoices` outside `handleChange` function.

Comment: @Layhout, Its working, but I'm thinking of storing it into the array inside the handleChange, and then `join` it before sending it to the `useState`, is it possible?

Comment: if your state is already an array, just push the value into state. pushing the value into an array first is unnecessary.